# Navigation drawer not getting rendered in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, navbar, hamburger-menu

Hey guys i am new to react-native and trying to build navigation drawer with hamburger icon on navigation bar. I can see the navigation bar but failed to render hamburger icon . Also the code is not getting rendered when i try to integrate it with other screen
Here is my code for toolbar.js

```
class toolbar extends Component {
  render(){
    var navigator = this.props.navigator;
    return (
    <ToolbarAndroid
     title={this.props.title}
     navIcon={require('./img/menu.png')}
     style = {styles.toolbar}
     titleColor={'white'}
     onIconClicked={this.props.sidebarRef}/>
    );
  }
}
```

And OpenDrawerFromToolbar.js code

```
var navigationView = (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
      <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left'}}>I m in the Drawer!</Text>
      </View>

    </ScrollView>
);

return (
  <DrawerLayoutAndroid
    drawerWidth={windowsWidth/1.5}
    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
    renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
    ref={'DRAWER'}>
    <Toolbar style={styles.toolbar}
        title={'Calendar'}
        navigator={this.props.navigator}
        sidebarRef={()=>this._setDrawer()}/>
    <View style={{alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
      <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>Hi MiaMia</Text>
    </View>
  </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
);
}

 _setDrawer() {
   this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer();
  }
 }
```

when running OpenDrawerFromToolbar.js solely it runs without rendering the hamburger icon. when i try to integrate with some other views it fails to get rendered. can anybody guide me through this?
[image: icons not displaying]
[image: another example where i am just getting icon title]

Thanks alot in advance. Any queries or doubts are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send me your project file structure snapshot with your image/icons folder.. ...

I don't think you can implement toolbar style like this :

```
<Toolbar style={styles.toolbar} //here is the error 
 title={'Calendar'} 
 navigator={this.props.navigator} 
 sidebarRef={()=>this._setDrawer()}/>
```

And send me your toolbar style stylesheet too..

Its better to implement toolbar style in toolbar.js file .. but still let me have a look at your style first ..

Comment: hey riten i have edited my question you can have a look at it. by the way can you guide me where to store icons because the problem i face that no icons are getting rendered in toolbar

Comment: folder structure is like : icons>color>menu.png so try like this format once : navIcon={require('../icons/color/menu.png')}.. in your case

Comment: for more information [click here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html)